# What is the easiest and best practice way to setting all contexts to 0 in Dialogflow's node.js fulfillment?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

Dialogflow has a `.clearOutgoingContexts()`function but seems to be deprecated, I wonder if looping through all contexts and setting their `lifespan` to 0 is the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you saw issue [dialogflow](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/217)

Currently, there is no better way to do that [solution](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/217#issuecomment-482667717)